# CSCore: NullReferenceException at StopNative() while stopping the playback

Tags: c#, pointers, unsafe, cscore

I'm trying to write a simple console application that plays a MP3 file using CSCore library. In the documentation it says that the Playback state will automatically change to Stopped once the file is finished playing which seems to be the outcome after a **Stop()** method is automatically called by CSCore at the end of the file stream. The **Stop()** method calls **StopNative()** where the exception arises.

Below is the code I've written:

```
static MMDevice mmdev = MMDeviceEnumerator.DefaultAudioEndpoint(DataFlow.Render, Role.Multimedia);
static AudioSessionManager AuSem;
static AudioSessionEnumerator AuSeEn;
static CSCore.SoundOut.ISoundOut soundout;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string file = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\bruh.mp3";
    soundout = new CSCore.SoundOut.DirectSoundOut();
    AuSem = AudioSessionManager2.FromMMDevice(mmdev);
    AuSeEn = AuSem.QueryInterface<AudioSessionManager2>().GetSessionEnumerator();
    IWaveSource AudioSource = CSCore.Codecs.CodecFactory.Instance.GetCodec(file);
    soundout.Initialize(AudioSource);
    soundout.Play();
}
```

The Exception that arise after playing is finished is:
[image: Exception]

The Exception point during debugging is:
[image]

I've noticed that the **StopNative()** is called 2 times successfully before the exception rises. Here I want to admit that I'm totally a newbie in pointers and do not understand what exactly is written in **StopNative()**.

I also like to mention that I've already tried contacted CSCore owner regarding the same problem and he gave me a link to his [article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/644130/NET-COM-Interop-using-Postbuild) which is beyond my understanding.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: At that mentioned article, there are source codes added - try to download them and look what is the person doing there ~ reuse his code. He is trying to also play some sounds (but from different threads), but it might essencialy resolve your problem.

Comment: @Tatranskymedved I cannot find any source code related to playing or stopping in the article or in the project attached with the article. Can you please point where exactly I have to look for in the article.

Comment: [Download source - 679 KB](https://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/644130/comimport_src.zip) & [Download demo project - 193 KB](https://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/644130/comimport_demo.zip)

Comment: It is not just about playing & stopping, it is about invoking those methods the way that is written in the article.